# Threejs Coordinates not matching with the coordinates of the Intesects of the Ray Caster

Tags: three.js, 3d-model, photogrammetry, threejs-editor

```
// Step 1 
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(10,aspectRatio,0.0001,100000)
    this.camera.position.x = 2;
    this.camera.position.y = 2;
    this.camera.position.z = 2;
// Step 2
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(this.background_color)
    this.create_sphere(this.camera.position, 0.01)
//Step 3
    const mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
    var mtl = await mtlLoader.loadAsync( this.url +'baked_mesh.mtl')

    this.loaderOBJ.setMaterials(mtl)
    this.model = await this.loaderOBJ.loadAsync(this.url + 'baked_mesh.obj') // url = https://wound-care.azurewebsites.net/models/bfe59b59-da40-4db4-b662-24461c0cff1d/
// Step 4
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: this.canvas, antialias: true });
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(this.canvas.clientWidth, this.canvas.clientHeight);
```

Step 1: Setup Camera

Step 2 : Setup Scene

Step 3: Load OBJ

Step 4: Setup Renderer

```
const mouse_click = (event:any) => {      
      if(event.which == 1){
        setRaycaster(event)
        var intersect = this.raycaster.intersectObject(this.pickableObjects[0])
        console.log(intersect)
        if(intersect.length >0){
          this.scene.add(measurementLabel)
          this.points.push(intersect[0].point)
          this.mouse_points.push(Object.assign({}, this.mouse))
          this.count+=1
          if(this.count == 1){
            var line_geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints([intersect[0].point,intersect[0].point.clone()])
            this.line = new THREE.LineSegments(             line_geometry,new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({                color:0x00FF00,transparent:true,opacity:1,               side:THREE.FrontSide,depthWrite:true,linecap:'square'              }))
            this.line.position.z = 0.002
            this.scene.add(this.line)
            this.drawingLine = true
          }
              this.ctrl_renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', on_move, false)

     }
}
let tirangle = new THREE.Triangle( intersects[0],new THREE.Vector3(2,2,2), intersects[intersects.length - 1])
      this.render_triangle(tirangle) // intersects[0] = ray Caster Intersect point 1
                                     // intersect[intersects.length -1] is the last intersect [!
```

The render triangle is implemented as

```
    render_triangle(triangle:Triangle){    
          let triangle_geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry()
          triangle_geom.setFromPoints([triangle.a, triangle.b, triangle.c])
          let triangle_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000})
let triangle_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(triangle_geom,triangle_material)
          this.scene.add(triangle_mesh)
          this.animate()
}
```

The rendered Triangle is not on the with the intersect points is not on the Model but else where, where as the points given to the triangle are the intersects captured from the ray caster intesectObject

output of the above code snippet

[image]

Comment: What exactly is `intersects`? `intersectObjects` returns an array of objects, not vectors. Could you show how you define the variable `intersects`?

Comment: intersects array is the array of point of intersections with the object.

Comment: Ok. Next question: what does `this.render_triangle()` look like?

Comment: `render_triangle(triangle:Triangle){

    let triangle_geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry()
    triangle_geom.setFromPoints([triangle.a, triangle.b, triangle.c])
    console.log(triangle.a, triangle.b, triangle.c)

    let triangle_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color:0xff0000
    })
    let triangle_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(triangle_geom, triangle_material)
    console.log(triangle_mesh)
    // triangle_mesh.worldToLocal(triangle.a)
    this.scene.add(triangle_mesh)
    this.animate()
  }`

Comment: Edited the question, Please have a look

Comment: Still can't find the issue. Could it be in another part of your code that you're not providing? Maybe `setRaycaster()`? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example